# getting the null values when i use the model class to get data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the datasnapshot that comes to a model class list,but now i am getting null values. when i debug i could find that my model class is not actualy taking the data from my satasnapshot andd adding to messages

my code i am using now.

```
model class
package com.teamta.artiando.models;

public class MatchModel {

private String last_message;
public String last_message_sender_id;
public Object last_message_timestamp;
public Object timestamp;
public User user1;
public User user2;

public MatchModel(String last_message, String last_message_sender_id, Object last_message_timestamp, Object timestamp, User user1, User user2) {
    this.last_message = last_message;
    this.last_message_sender_id = last_message_sender_id;
    this.last_message_timestamp = last_message_timestamp;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.user1 = user1;
    this.user2 = user2;


}
public MatchModel(){

}

public String getLast_message() {
    return last_message;
}

public void setLast_message(String last_message) {
    this.last_message = last_message;
}

public String getLast_message_sender_id() {
    return last_message_sender_id;
}

public void setLast_message_sender_id(String last_message_sender_id) {
    this.last_message_sender_id = last_message_sender_id;
}

public Object getLast_message_timestamp() {
    return last_message_timestamp;
}

public void setLast_message_timestamp(Object last_message_timestamp) {
    this.last_message_timestamp = last_message_timestamp;
}

public Object getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Object timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public User getUser1() {
    return user1;
}

public void setUser1(User user1) {
    this.user1 = user1;
}

public User getUser2() {
    return user2;
}

public void setUser2(User user2) {
    this.user2 = user2;
}

public static class User {

    private String name;
    public String profilepic_url;
    public String userId;

    public User(String name, String profilepic_url, String userId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.profilepic_url= profilepic_url;
        this.userId =userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getProfilepic_url() {
        return profilepic_url;
    }

    public void setProfilepic_url(String profilepic_url) {
        this.profilepic_url = profilepic_url;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

}
```

}

on my manager class i use

```
 private  ValueEventListener userCalueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        MatchModel messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(MatchModel.class);
        name.add(messages);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("year", "DatabaseError: "+databaseError);
    }
};
```

this is my query

```
  public void observeUserdata() {        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("matches").orderByChild(userId).equalTo(true).addValueEventListener(userCalueEventListener);
}
```

my firbase looks like

```
matches
  |
  |-kwerrwuw8iaajasd    // i have 30 key like this key in the matches in this node
          |- Kweyatsgdywywyww
          |- last_message
          |- last_senderuserid
          |- timestamp
          |-user1
          |    |- name
          |    |- profile_pic
          |    |- user_id
          |-user2
          |    |- name
          |    |- profile_pic
          |    |- user_id
          |- Kweyatsgdywywyww
```

Comment: where are you setting the data to your model ? and have you checked if the values are coming null from firebase ?

Comment: no,values are comming from firebase.. it comes null when i use the model class to extract the datasnapshot @Umair

Comment: if there are no values then you need to check from where you are sending the data to firebase. or check if firebase has the data.

Comment: sorry i have edited the comments. @Umair .. i am getting the correct values from firebase but  when i use the model class to extract the datasnapshot , then it becomes null

Comment: I have debugged the issue the error occurs when i use  dataSnapshot.getValue(MatchModel.class);  // model class to extract data@Umair

Comment: then you are getting the model in wrong way. Please see the answer of alex. it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an empty constructor inside all the model classes,
if their is inner classes in model class you need to add an empty constructor to that class also

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a loop inside onDataChange() method and access your data one by one and put in your list, then you will be able to get the list of messages.

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

          yourClass obj=data.getValue(yourClass.class);
          yourList.add(obj);
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `null` because you are using a wrong `DatabaseReference`.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() 
    .child("matches")
    .orderByChild(userId)
    .equalTo(true).addValueEventListener(userCalueEventListener);
```

As I see in your database structure, you are trying to order the children by user objects and  you cannot query this way. What can you do instead is to query after the `timestamp`, which is a direct child of the `matches` node. Your query should look like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() 
    .child("matches")
    .orderByChild(userId)
    .equalTo(true).addValueEventListener(userCalueEventListener);
```

Comment: orderByChild(userId) , userId is a string that i get from the bundle and directly setting.

Comment: That's the same thing. You do not have a child `userId` which is a string under that node, you have object nodes.